# key map sublimeREPL commands in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, keymapping, sublimerepl

I'm trying to map keyboard shortcuts for SublimeREPL plugin commands. Looking at SublimeREPL it looks like a menu item command is defined as:

[Default.sublime-commands](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/config/Scala/Default.sublime-commands)
    {
        "caption": "SublimeREPL: SBT for opened folder",
        "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
        {
            "id": "repl_sbt",
            "file": "config/Scala/Main.sublime-menu"
        }
    }

or in

[Main.sublime-menu](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/config/Scala/Main.sublime-menu)

```
               {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "SBT for opened folder",
                 "id": "repl_sbt",
                 "mnemonic": "b",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "external_id": "scala",
                    "cmd": {"linux": ["sbt"],
                            "osx": ["sbt"],
                            "windows": ["sbt"]},
                    "soft_quit": "\nexit\n",
                    "cwd": "$folder",
                    "cmd_postfix": "\n", 
                    "extend_env": {"osx": {"EMACS": "1", "PATH": "{PATH}:/usr/local/bin"},
                                   "linux": {"EMACS": "1", "PATH": "{PATH}:/usr/local/bin"},
                                   "windows": {"EMACS": "1"}},
                    "suppress_echo": false, 
                    "syntax": "Packages/Scala/Scala.tmLanguage"
                    }
                }
```

I've tried making a keybinding in my SublimeREPL.sublime-settings to:

```
[{ "keys": ["super+shift+k"], "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
        {
            "id": "repl_sbt",
            "file": "config/Scala/Main.sublime-menu"
        }
}]
```

But when I try to use it the Sublime console just says:

> no command for selector: noop:

Same if I map it to:

```
[{ "keys": ["super+shift+k"],  "command": "repl_open",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "external_id": "scala",
                    "cmd": {"linux": ["sbt"],
                            "osx": ["sbt"],
                            "windows": ["sbt"]},
                    "soft_quit": "\nexit\n",
                    "cwd": "$folder",
                    "cmd_postfix": "\n", 
                    "extend_env": {"osx": {"EMACS": "1", "PATH": "{PATH}:/usr/local/bin"},
                                   "linux": {"EMACS": "1", "PATH": "{PATH}:/usr/local/bin"},
                                   "windows": {"EMACS": "1"}},
                    "suppress_echo": false, 
                    "syntax": "Packages/Scala/Scala.tmLanguage"
                    }

}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first keybinding is correct and should work as expected. Place is in **Preferences -> Key Bindings - User** file.

```
[{ "keys": ["super+shift+k"], "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
        {
            "id": "repl_sbt",
            "file": "config/Scala/Main.sublime-menu"
        }
}]
```

based on your description, I suspect that some other command is hijacking super+shift+k.

```
>>> sublime.log_commands(True)
```

will let you see what's get called when.

Comment: You are right that did work. My problem was that I was putting it in SublimeREPL.sublime-settings instead of my User keybindings file ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap